# Expect this or that, how to include an OR in unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, expect, assertions, buster.js

I'm using buster.js and the "expect" assertions. I want the assertion to succeed in at least one of:

`expect(req.body.data._id).toBe('foo bar baz');`

or

`expect(req.body.data.id).toBe('foo bar baz');`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at the [relevant documentation](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/modules/referee/#expectations) it looks like you want

```
expect([req.body.data._id, req.body.data.id]).toContain('foo bar baz');
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answer from @glenn jackman is good enough, to get more semantic related reading, you could use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function with some `isEqual` analog. Example:

```
var isEqual = function(first) { return function(second) { return first === second; }; }

[1,2,3].some(isEqual(2); // true

expect([1,2,3].some(isEqual(2))).toBeTrue(); // passed

expect([1,2,3].some(isEqual(4))).toBeTrue(); // failed
```

Or you could walk further on this way:

```
var someOf = function(array) { return array.some.bind(array); };

expect(someOf([1,2,3])(isEqual(1))).toBeTrue(); // passed
```

Get rid of brackets:

```
var someOf = function(array) {
    return { isEqual: function(x) { return array.some(isEqual(x)); } };
}

expect(someOf([1,2,3]).isEqual(4)).toBeTrue();
```

I believe you can do more with creating custom 'expectations' with [buster.referee.add](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/modules/referee/#methods).

Answer (score 0):

`expect(req.body.data._id || req.body.data.id).toBe('foo bar baz');`

Comment: Are you sure this works? What if `req.body.data._id` is `'mango'` and `req.body.data.id` is `'foo bar baz'`

Comment: Are you sure? Because that's not how javascript works. In the example I gave above, it basically becomes this `expect('mango' || 'foo bar baz').toBe('foo bar baz')` which boils down to `expect('mango').toBe('foo bar baz')`. That's what the `||` operator does - returns the **first** truthy value

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.